# complexity for select query where id in list and id is indexed for table

Tags: mysql, indexing, time-complexity

What is complexity(scanned row per query)  of the following query?

```
select col_name from table where id in (list).
```

table is indexed on id. 
does every row will be scanned and fetched only which are having id in list or it is going to access only rows which are having given id in list?

Comment: did you got the answer for it?

Answer (score 2):

`EXPLAIN` may give you a guesstimate.  The following will be precise:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT city, population FROM canada WHERE id IN (295560,295007,297104,293500,293583,297001,291726,296573,296239,295210,293022,295192,293038);
+----------------+------------+
| city           | population |
+----------------+------------+
| Abbotsford     |     151685 |
| Drummondville  |      59489 |
| Duncan         |      22199 |
| Glace Bay      |      21504 |
| Grande Prairie |      41463 |
| New Glasgow    |      20322 |
| Orangeville    |      32641 |
| Ottawa         |     874433 |
| Prince George  |      65558 |
| Saskatoon      |     198957 |
| Stratford      |      30234 |
| Waterloo       |     110800 |
| White Rock     |      66450 |
+----------------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show session status like 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 13    |  -- Note
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that 13 rows were read, not the 5484 that are in the table.
(This requires a KEY on `id`.)

Comment: if there are n rows in database, the complexity would be m*log(n) considering id column is indexed. is it correct?

Comment: @RajatAggarwal - Since the index is a BTree, then technically it is n*logn.  But since the base of the log is something like 100, that part can typically be ignored.  More importantly, the non-leaf nodes are very likely to be cached -- thereby avoiding I/O.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal - So, technically 13 IN items will take about 13*log(5484), or about 26.  That is 13 BTree lookups will touch about 2 nodes per lookup.